# ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator is not launching in Visual Stusio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

When I add new item and choose the "ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator", I get an error message "this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing Project Templates"

I get the same error when I choose the "ADO.NET DbConext Generator". There's a 4.2 version of it and it works.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 in windows 7 64bit. (Just reinstalled SP1), Entity Framework June 2011 CTP, and the just released Entity Framework 4.2. All the projects in the solution are taregting the CTP framework.
I already ran devenv.exe /setup & devenv.exe /installvstemplates

I have two questions:
How do I find out why ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator is not working? Is there a v4.2 version of it?

The error message seems to indicate the template tried to load Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design but there was a problem. I want to find what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CTP 2011 installed and if your project targets special CTP .NET 4.2 target you must use only features from CTP = only the POCO template shipped with CTP. Nothing else will work because CTP is intrusive and it breaks functionality of old EF features and designer.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design I have on my computer is 10.6.10617.1 while the template is looking for 10.0.0.0. What I did is rebuilt the vsix template extension to use 10.6 instead. There are a few templates in the gallery which produce this problem and these need to modified.